# Не подключиться к серверу с помощью filezilla

Tags: файлы, ftp

Всегда спокойно подключался через этот фтп клиент, и соответственно в настройки никогда не лазил. Сейчас попробывал подключиться и вылетает такая ошибка

```
Статус: Соединение установлено, ожидание приглашения...
Ответ: 220 ProFTPD 1.3.5a Server (ProFTPD) [194.58.97.43]
Команда: AUTH TLS
Ответ: 234 AUTH TLS successful
Статус: Инициализирую TLS...
Ошибка: Ошибка GnuTLS -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Статус: Сервер неверно закрыл TLS соединение
Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу
```

Comment: ищем в гугл "gnutls error 110 filezilla"

Comment: Что-то не похоже на онтопик. Разве что вы автор кода сервера или filezilla.

Answer (score 4):

Получилось решить проблему только переключением способа шифрования - вместо "Использовать явный FTP через TLS если доступен" ставлю "Использовать обычный FTP (небезопасно)".